# how to get value from Json in the click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm working on a project. and can't seen to get this working. i make a call to my virtual localhost and get back product info from Json then place them in the buttons. i have a click function for the buttons and pass the item ID to my  id. but some how it doesn't display item id. please take a look to see what went wrong. thanks.

```
 function loadItem() {
    var contentRows = $("#prod-diplay");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/items',
        success: function (data, status) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                var ID = item.id;
                var name = item.name;
                var price = item.price;
                var quantity = item.quantity;
            var row = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
                row += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="product"' + ID + '>';
                row += '<p id="id">' + ID + '</p>';
                row += '<p id="name">' + name + '</p>';
                row += '<p id="price"> Price: ' + price + '</p>';
                row += '<p id="quanity"> Quantity Left: ' + quantity + ' </p>';
                row += '</button>';
                row += '</div>'
                contentRows.append(row);
                $
                $('#product' + ID ).click(function(){// get this working. left off from here when start back up. 
                    $('#vending').val(item.id);
                });

            });


        },
        error: function () {
            $('#errorMessages')
                .append($('<li>')
                    .attr({
                        class: 'list-group-item list-group-item-danger'
                    })
                    .text('Error calling web service.  Please try again later.'));
        }

    });

}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9" id="prod-diplay"></div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="displayItem" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
   Item:
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
   <input class="form-control" id="vending" placeholder="item no." required/>
   </div>
   </div>
  <button type="button" id="purchase" class="btn btn-default">Make Purchase</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: What happens when you click `$('#product' + ID )`

Comment: suppose to display an item ID#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are assigning the `id` to your button.

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="product"' + ID + '>'
```

If you inspect this button you will see

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="product" 1="">..</button>
```

Check the id, it's `id="product"` and your ID from json is getting created as another attribute to the button.

To solve this you need to put quotes("") properly.
Like this

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="product' + ID + '">'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `$` here

```
//Rest of the code
contentRows.append(row);
$ //<--- this one may be unwanted
$('#product' + ID ).click(function(){
$('#vending').val(item.id);

//Rest of the code
```

To address your problem you can delegate the event

```
$('body').on('click','#product'+ID ,function(){
  $('#vending').val(item.id);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for catching it. combine from above solution have worked . thanks.